# SVG filter with variable?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters

I have an SVG glow filter implemented like so:

```
<filter id="outline">
    <feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" operator="dilate" radius="2"></feMorphology>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1" result="dilated"></feGaussianBlur>
    <feFlood style="flood-color: #RRGGBB"></feFlood>
    <feComposite in2="dilated" operator="in"></feComposite>
    <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
    </feMerge>
</filter>
```

This works nicely, but only for one specific glow colour.

I would like to be able to have an arbitrary glow colour, in some way passing a variable in to the `flood-color` property.

I have tried using `currentColor`, but this seems to be the colour as it is when the filter is defined, not when it is applied.

I *could* define a filter for each colour (there will be a limited number of them) but it would be nicer - and certainly more space-efficient - to only need to define it once. Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: Just set the style using JavaScript... Or when you use d3js, you can define the style as a function.

Answer (score 1):

In the next example the `flood-color` is the current color. If you click the svg element you toggle the class "blue".  The `color` of the svg element is `red` the color of the `.blue` is blue.

When you toggle the class blue the filter is changing the flood color.

```js
test.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  test.classList.toggle("blue")
})
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-anchor: middle;
  dominant-baseline: middle;
  width:100px;
  color:red;
}

.blue{color:blue;}
```

```html
<svg id="test"  viewBox="0 0 100 70">
  
  <filter id="outline">
    <feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" operator="dilate" radius="2"></feMorphology>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1" result="dilated"></feGaussianBlur>
    <feFlood style="flood-color: currentcolor"></feFlood>
    <feComposite in2="dilated" operator="in"></feComposite>
    <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
    </feMerge>
</filter>
  
<text x="50" y="40" filter="url(#outline)">click</text>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: but you are defining the color inside the SVG. I guess he meant such situation: https://jsfiddle.net/68ag3L0v/ where he will be using the filter on html elements. in your case we cannot reuse the same filter with a different color, or I am wrong?

Comment: In your example the current color is the color of the svg element, i.e. black. Maybe the OP should comment to explain if they want to apply the filter to an HTML element or use it inside the svg

Comment: Sorry, yes, it is for use on HTML elements - but even if it were for SVG elements within the same SVG, suppose the SVG contains three balls I want to make glow in different colours.